# SQL join a table on a branching condition

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I'm trying to perform an SQL join "with a twist", something like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM a
JOIN b ON /* a.type == 'any' ? b.id IS NULL : b.id = a.id */
```

where the comment is written in C-like syntax. How can I express what I want in SQL? (Preferably ANSI, but specific to Oracle Database is fine too.)

Comment: not familiar with oracle and i am not sure what your trying to do but for a shot in the dark do you mean:  `ON (a.type = 'any' and b.id is null) OR (a.id=b.id)`

Comment: @gordatron: Yes, this works too in my case, but it relies on certain additional assumptions that I didn't specify in the question. So, it works for me, but not as a general-purpose answer ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM a
JOIN b ON (a.type  = 'any' AND b.id IS NULL) 
       OR (a.type <> 'any' AND b.id = a.id)
```